# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR on the Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

First of all, on the local machine app is working.

But when I type `heroku run rake db:migrate` I get an error in the console. Something like this:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "subject_items" does not exist
>   : ALTER TABLE "subject_items" ADD "student_id" integer/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
>
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "subject_items" does not exist
>   : ALTER TABLE "subject_items" ADD "student_id" integer
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/act
>
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
>   /app/db/migrate/20151018091819_add_student_id_to_subject_items.rb:3:in change'

As I said locally works.

Migration filed mentioned in log looks like this:

```
class AddStudentIdToSubjectItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :subject_items, :student_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Some if the `schema.db`:

```
create_table "subject_items", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "teacher_id"
t.integer  "student_id"
end
```

Where could be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that's his second sentence. What bugs me is that the error is saying that "subject_items" doesn't exist as a "relation"... Isn't it a table ?

Comment: I have a table "subject_items" and a model SubjectItem. But locally works (also on Postgres) and it's  a little confusing for me.

Comment: I've got a migration file `20151018091819_add_student_id_to_subject_items.rb` but there aren't migration files for subject_items. I've pull whole repo from github, so I've got only `scheba.rb`. On heroku i type `heroku run rake db:schema:load` (works). But `db:migrate` raises an error.

Comment: Did you try to rake with production? rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: Can you log into prod and see if the table exists?  "Heroku run rails c" and do 'SubjectItems'

Comment: "there aren't migration files for subject_items" => That's it. You should have a migration file creating your subject_items table, otherwise it won't be created in production.